# Google Script Syntax for CELL CONTAINS TEXT

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to write several if statements with multiple conditions, of which some conditions are simply looking for cells that contain text. Below is an example of the script I am using. In this example I need value [2] to be the correct syntax for cell contains text. I tried several ways including <>"" which does not work. Is there a way to express cell contains text without adding additional lines to the code? Thank you for any help.

```
function onEdit2(e){

var ss = e.source;

var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

var row = e.range.getRow();

var col = e.range.getColumn();

  var validSheets = ["3","4","5","6"];

var value = [];

if(row > 1 && col <=7 && validSheets.includes(sheet.getName())){

value = sheet.getRange(row,2,2,5).getDisplayValues().flat();


  if(value[0] == "Outgoing" && value [1] == "FASTWAY" && value [2] === <>"" && value [3] == "TARGET"){

sheet.getRange(row,10).setValue("USE HEAT TREATED PALLET");

}}
```

Comment: Your code is not written in `Excel VBA` language. Please tag proper programming language.

Comment: Hello. Stackoverflow would not let me add "Google" but I will change the tags. Thanks.

Comment: If you are using `google-sheet` then tag it as `google-sheets`

Answer (score 0):

You can test whether a text string has a non-zero length by comparing it to an empty text string, like this:

`values[2] !== ''`

...or simply by referring to its `length` property, like this:

```
function onEdit2(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.rowStart <= 1
    || e.range.columnStart > 7
    || !sheet.getName().match(/^(3|4|5|6)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const values = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 2, 5).getDisplayValues().flat();
  if (values[0] === 'Outgoing'
    && values[1] === 'FASTWAY'
    && values[2].length
    && values[3] === 'TARGET') {
    sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 10).setValue('USE HEAT TREATED PALLET');
  }
}
```

Comment: The first solution worked as expected- thank you so much!! I will review your other solution as well. Thanks again!